# preg_match_all in php showing result blank

Tags: php, regex

How do i match this with REGEXP and PHP ?

```
"s:6:\"[\"50\"]\";",
"s:5:\"[\"1\"]\";"
```

I want to match numbers between : `[\"50\"]` this only or could be one or more.

I have a pattern and want to take only numbers from `json_encode` value also `serialize()` in php this is code :

```
$result = [];
        foreach($impressions as $impression) {
            preg_match_all('/\x5C/', $impression->subcategories, $result);
        }

return $result;
```

if no preg_match then here is result :

```
"s:6:\"[\"50\"]\";",
"s:5:\"[\"1\"]\";"
```

I am using this to match only digit where \ is so i can take number only like 50 or 1

Any idea how i can pic number with regular expressions ? value hex not works '/\x5C/' showing me result blank but here : [Works fine](http://regexr.com/) if i put result and test with same REGEXP.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are not _capturing_ anything in your pattern, so what result do you expect?

Comment: i want to capture only values : "s:6:\"[\"50\"]\";", ---- "s:5:\"[\"1\"]\";" 50 or 1

Comment: i tried this : \d{1,9}(?=\x5C)

Comment: I read this 3 times. I can only guess at what you're asking. But if you're looking to pull back all the numbers in a string then you can use regex `/\d+/`.

Comment: don't wanted to include these : "s:6: only between \"50\" number 50

Comment: I'm not trying to be a jerk here, but I understand even less now.  How about this, what if you type the strings you're anticipating and then the result you're expecting? `$stringIn -> $matches`  `"s:6:\"[\"50\"]\";" -> '6', '50'`

Comment: _“i tried this : `\d{1,9}(?=\x5C)`”_ – and which part(s) of the input string are you _capturing_ here, in your opinion?

Comment: What about `\[\\"(\d+)\\"\]`? https://regex101.com/r/gU7dW0/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can not go through an array of strings that way with preg_match_all – your `$result` array gets overwritten in each loop iteration.

And then, you need to *capture* the numbers you want to see in your result set. To do that, you must mask the `[`, `]` and `\` characters each with another `\` – and then capture the digits in the middle by putting them in `(` and `)`

```
$impressions[] = "s:6:\"[\"50\"]\";";
$impressions[] = "s:5:\"[\"1\"]\";";

foreach($impressions as $impression) {
  preg_match_all('#\[\\"([0-9]+)\\"\]#', $impression, $matches); // I chose # as delimiter
     // here – with so many \ involved, we don’t need / around it to add to the confusion

  $results[] = $matches; // $matches will be overwritten in each iteration, so we
    // preserve its content here by putting it into the $results array
}

var_dump($results);
```